# live bootable tiny distro for burn-in testing of LCDs?

Tags: video, monitors

I'd like to stress test used LCD monitors for problems that may become apparent after they've been in use for a while. I'm looking for those with components that fail because of heat.

To those ends I'd like to set up a workstation that has a live bootable CD that will do something that's someone intensive as far as the screen is concerned. I've found distros that have LCD test patterns, but those are static images. I want something that will show me that a monitor will flake out after an hour of use.

Also, it would be nice if this could be a simple command. This workstation will be used by people who aren't linux savvy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you are going to get the results you want from a test program.  I've worked at a company that produced consumer electronics and the test facility there had several environmental units that would simulate scenarios like this that would cause failures.  One was just a simple box with a heating element that would allow you to put electronics in it and heat it up to some specified temp (usually 90-140F) and then use the device until it failed or experienced whatever problem you were trying to reproduce.  If you really want to test for component failure that is the best way.